# Microsoft Excel - If you make a new conditional formatting rule, which applies to a certain selection, how to make the same apply on every sheet?

Tags: excel

This is a question which tries to apply conditional formatting across sheets.

Answer (score 1):

If the range is the same on all sheets, you can:

1. Copy the cells wherein you added the conditional formatting rule;
2. Select all sheets where you want to apply the rule (either holding Shift or Ctrl while selecting the sheets);
3. Select the range where you want to paste the formatting rule;
4. Paste special -> Formatting

The conditional formatting rule should be applied to all selected sheets.